# javaScript - JSON push() Formatting

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, fluent

How to push data to JSON variable in below format?

```
[
 "name":"sample name"
,"first_name":"sample first"
,"last_name":"sample last"
,"email":"sample.@mail.com"
]
```

but what's happening is the below format..

```
[
 {"name":"sample name"}
,{"first_name":"sample first"}
,{"last_name":"sample last"}
,{"email":"sample.@mail.com"}
]
```

I have to set it that way because I'm using fluentPDO.

Edit:

Below is part of my code...

```
var r = [];
angular.forEach($scope.fields, function(value, index) {
    var f = value.field;
    var o = {};
    o[f] = $('#'+value.id).val();
    r.push(o);
});
return angular.toJson(r);
```

On the PHP side (the one I call on `$.post()` method)...

```
$set = json_decode($_POST["fields"], true)
echo json_encode($set);
```

Comment: the first one is not a valid javascript format... you need to use object notation like `{
 "name":"sample name"
,"first_name":"sample first"
,"last_name":"sample last"
,"email":"sample.@mail.com"
}`

Comment: share your code so that we can have a look at it

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object not an array of objects so

```
var r = {};
angular.forEach($scope.fields, function (value, index) {
    r[value.field] = $('#' + value.id).val();
});
return angular.toJson(r);
```